# Global and local maximum and minimum of $\log(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to study $f(x,y) = \log(x+y)$.
The function is defined in $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y>-x\}$. The gradient is not null. Can I study the Hessian matrix to find global convexity?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $f$ is constant along the lines $x+y=r$ with $r>0$, and $r\to \log(r)$ is strictly increasing and concave in $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: So does exist global max?

Comment: @user495707 What do you think?

Comment: Yes but i can't found it

Comment: As regards the global maximum/minimum, consider the values of $f$ along the line $y=x$ with $x>0$: evaluate the limits: $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\log(x+x)$ and  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\log(x+x)$. What may we conclude?

Comment: f is not limited sup and inf.

Comment: You are correct, $\sup_D f=+\infty$ and  $\inf_D f=-\infty$.

Comment: So the function is not globally concave?

Comment: Yes, it is globally concave (not strictly concave).